# Alternative to putting if clauses in getters

Tags: angular

I have some lengthy if clauses which I need several times in one view. For example:

```
<div *ngIf="(
  this.strasseDropdown &&
  this.data.ort &&
  this.adressvorschlag().strassen.length > 0 &&
  this.formElementHasError(this.strasseDropdown)
)">...</div>
```

I put this in a getter like this:

```
get showStrasseDropdownErrors(): boolean {
  return (
    this.strasseDropdown &&
    this.data.ort &&
    this.adressvorschlag().strassen.length > 0 &&
    this.formElementHasError(this.strasseDropdown)
  );
}
```

But now I always get an ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError because binding getters to the view is not a good idea in Angular.
So what is the way to go in Angular to put if clauses like this to ruse them?

Comment: can you provide more information on the data? adressvorschlag(), this.formElementHasError(this.strasseDropdown).

I think the idomatic way is to provide an observable<boolean> which emits if the evaluation of the condition changes. Then you could subscribte to it with the async-pipe

Comment: So the solution in this case was to ensure all the variables I compare are not undefined. For that it was enough to convert `this.strasseDropdown` to a boolean like this: `Boolean(this.strasseDropdown)`